# TFS2013: How do I get the product backlog items in order via SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to list the product backlog items from TFS (2013) in backlog order, using SQL. I want the order to be the same as seen in the on-prem web portal when I look at the current iteration.

I can't seem to find where this order is stored. We've got the scrum template applied - maybe the field doesn't exist in the DimWorkItem table at all?

The following query retrieves the list I want, just not in the perfect order.

```
select  t1.System_id, 
        t1.System_Title, 
        t1.System_State, 
        t1.system_rev, 
        t1.Microsoft_VSTS_Common_BacklogPriority 
        from Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItem t1
INNER JOIN 
(
    select System_id, MAX(system_rev) system_rev 
    FROM Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItem where 
    System_WorkItemType='Product Backlog Item' and AreaSK=62 
    group by System_id
) pbi_recentT
ON t1.System_Id=pbi_recentT.System_Id and t1.system_rev=pbi_recentT.system_rev
order by IterationSK desc, Microsoft_VSTS_Common_BacklogPriority asc
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the ```IterationSK desc, ``` in the last line? If it's the priority you want to sort it by, the other column could be throwing off your sorting.

Comment: Iterations are incremental numbers (basically sprints in Scrum), but the backlog priority seems to be very large random numbers. I think you need an intimate knowledge of TFS 2013 storage to answer this question :-)

Comment: *slowly walks away :)

Answer (score 0):

The backlog in TFS is an ordered list of work items, the order of the backlog items is dictated by the the “Order” field as defined in the process configuration. The process templates that we ship use different fields for this “Order” field. The Scrum template uses the field called “Backlog Priority”, while the Agile and CMMI templates use the field called “Stack Rank”.

So in your case, order by Backlog Priority is correct.

Comment: If I compare the results of my query to the view in the tfs Web Portal (on premise) it's not the same order, either at main backlog or specific area iteration levels. The Stacked Rank field is empty, so there must be another field that's representing the order on the web portal. Maybe I'll hook up SQL Profiler to discover what's going on. Maybe there's another table that stores the 'web order'.

Comment: As you are using scrum process template, you should use "Backlog Priority" field.

Comment: Looking at the SQL generated by visiting the page - I think it's taking into consideration the priority order of ancestral items first, and maybe even which iteration the parents are in. So it's not as simple as ordering by an individual work item's priority. Maybe the TVF GetWorkItemsTree() can do this for me?

Comment: I'm a little confused about your query, doesn't order by Backlog Priority give you the correct order as on web access?

Comment: No. In the simplest case it might. But when you impose hierarchy to your product backlog items I think the deep items  can't be compared as equals, the parent / ancestry backlog priority needs to be taken into account. It may be further confused by having parents coming from different Areas, where child PBIs have been brought into a different area to the parent! If I work out the sql with recursive CTE interrogating the links -  I'll let you know.